# Mongodb query: Find the population of certain states using the $in query operator in the $match pipeline

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to find find the population of certain states using the $in query operator in the $match pipeline using Mongodb Query.

I tried running this code but I keep getting errors. What am I doing wrong?

```
db.getCollection("statistics").aggregate(

[
     { $match: {"pop": 1}, "state": {$in: ["MN", "IA", "ND", "SD", "WI"]}}
   ]
);
```

Comment: Can you add the schema and also the expected format  clearly in the questation?

Answer (score 0):

use `$match` with `$and` criteria

```
db.getCollection("statistics").aggregate(
    [
        {$match: {
            $and: [
                    {"pop" :{ $eq : 1}},
                    {"state": {$in: ["MN", "IA", "ND", "SD", "WI"]}}
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
);
```

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't produce any outputs. Any suggestions?

Comment: can you post the test data with expected output? and what is the version of mongoDB?